# Android studio: fill the gallery with some photos for user to choose from

Tags: android, android-studio, onclick, gallery

I have the below code to have the user clicked on the original pic, he can then select a photo from gallery to replace the original pic.
[image: Original pic]

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
Uri imageUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    final ImageView exampleImage = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.exampleImageView);
    exampleImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // [TODO] Implement application behavior when the user clicks the profile picture
            //Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            GalleryActivity();
        }
    });
}
private void GalleryActivity(){
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        imageUri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }

}
```

however after I clicked the image, there are no photo to choose from the gallery (empty gallery). How do I do anything to fill the photo gallery with some photos for user to choose from?(I am using the emulator for the test)

[image: Empty Gallery]

Comment: Take some pictures with the camera

Comment: added the 2 pics

Comment: The 2? What 2 ? Take some was said.

Comment: I have no idea what you edited but even on an emulator you can use the Camera app to take as much pictures as you want.